# bad state: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

one day before this was completely working but now this say Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null.
this returns a document key but not its value I check a user id multiple time.

```
class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  List<ChoicesModel> options = [];
  String id = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      id = Get.parameters["id"] ?? "";
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(id),),
      body: id.isNotEmpty ? StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection(collectionQrCode).doc(id).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Some think is wrong"));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(data);
            return SizedBox(
              width: Get.width,
              child: Text("Noo"),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ) : const Text("No Key"),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to print/debug `snapshot.data?.data()`

Comment: i tried this only many time. this stream return a ducument id but not document

Comment: Try to check the db existence on `db.collection(collectionQrCode).doc(id)` and then print the snapshot

Comment: snapshot exist but data is null

Comment: try to check the firebase console if it's actually matching the doc path

Answer (score 1):

- It is because you have nothing stored inside the `doc id` specified in the database.

  - Try adding fields in the specified `id` and make sure the `document` is not `null`.